# I want to import boxcom api, but it didnt work.

Tags: java, api, import

I am not good at english, but I think you can understand my problem.

I want to import the boxcom java api, but it makes red line and does not work.
What is my mistake?

In boxcom developer center, I can see 'Box Java SDK sample app by Peter Rexer'.
He uses:

```
import com.box.boxjavalibv2.*;
import com.box.boxjavalibv2.dao.*;
```

But when I write `import com.box.boxjavalibv2.*;` Netbeans makes a red line and gives the error `package com.box.boxjavalibv2.* does not exist`
What does this mean? How can I use boxcom api?

Comment: Have you added corresponding JAR file(s) into your classpath?

Comment: @PradeepSimha Yes, I import all JAR files and test...But I cant find "com.box.boxjavaliv2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it

```
import com.box.boxjavalibv2.*;
```

Comment: @JaeminLee.. you said you wrote "import com.box.boxjavalibv2.;" which is wrong and system can't find it. It should be  "import com.box.boxjavalibv2.*;". Even if this doesn't solve then check which jar contains this box api and add it to your classpath

Comment: @G V Yes I know that i miss '*'. but in my java file I wrote correctly. hmm... It didnt work means I find classpath by myself?
In sdk, many jar. When I want to use some api, should i find in which jar file?

Comment: of course.. I believe you need to look for this - BoxJavaLibraryV2.jar

Comment: Open the jar file with winzip or winrar. You shall find the folder structure com.box.boxjavaliv2 there

Comment: There is no com.box.boxjavaliv2..I make an effort to find folder.
Thank you for your reply.